# HTTP Request from plugin - One or more erros occured

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have been trying to make a HTTP POST request from plugin without lucky.

I have the same code working fine in my console appication however in plugin I get the following error: "One or more erros occured". I tried to run it asynchronously but it did not work as well.

I really appreciate any idea, thank you!

```
       var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "KEY");

            // Request parameters
            queryString["chave"] = "key2";
            queryString["codigo_obra"] = codigoObra;
            queryString["codigo_bloco"] = codigoBloco;
            queryString["codigo_unidade"] = codigoUnidade;
            queryString["codigo_planta"] = codigoPlanta;
            var uri = "http://test?" + queryString;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("");

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                //This line gives me the error.
                response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
            }
```

Comment: sandboxed plugin and the url to call is an ip?

Comment: The error is "One or more erros occured". Guido, plugin is running in none!

Comment: Can you share a stacktrace? Did you run your console app on the same server that is processing your plugin? Did you add 'test' to your LMHOST file or to DNS?

Comment: I'm running the console app from my local machine. Now that you mentioned I tried to run that from server that is running my plugins assembly and got the same error. That should be something related with the server... is that possible the server or firewall is blocking the url I'm trying to access?

Comment: If you strip the code down to only operate on one record, then instead of getting the error message "One or more errors has occurred", you will get a real error message indicating what went wrong.  Also, using CRM's OrganizationService.Create may be easier than HTTP Post if you're working from a plugin anyway because it handles all the headers and bytes for you and you can just write the functional part of the code.